# C# Linq to Entities - Multiple joins on the same table

Tags: c#, join, linq-to-entities

I need to get groups of rows from a DB table according to:

1. filtering by user input
2. groups that correspond to the results from the filtering

I've tried several ideas for solutions but have fallen short with all of them.
For example, I attempted to use simple SQL commands (`executeStoryQuery` or something) where I first create a Common Table Expression but I run into trouble when I try create paging (I'm using DB2).

This is where I'm at now:

**The following does not actually work. I get an error when trying to use Contains on the `secondarySelect` before actually pulling the data from the DB**

```
//ctx => my Entities context
//userInput1 => int, userInput2 => int
//DB table: PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN (INTEGER),  
            GROUP_ID_COLUMN (CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA),  
            COLUMN1 (INTEGER),  
            COLUMN2 (INTEGER)
            COLUMN3 (VARCHAR(100))

var initialSelect = ctx.MY_TABLE
                    .Where(o => o.COLUMN1 == userInput1 && initSel.COLUMN2 == userInput2);

if(!string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput3))
{
    initialSelect = initialSelect.Where(o => o.COLUMN3.Contains(userInput3));
}

...
[More if()s of other columns]
...

initialSelect = initialSelect.Select(o => o.GROUP_ID_COLUMN);

var secondarySelect = from groups in ctx.MY_TABLE
                      join initialResults in initialSelect on groups.GROUP_ID_COLUMN equals initialResults.GROUP_ID_COLUMN
                      select groups.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN;

var finalSelect = from fullList in ctx.MY_TABLE
                  where secondarySelect.Contains(fullList.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN)
                  select fullList;
```

This fails upon trying to use `Contains` on a resultset which I have not yet actually pulled from the DB.
Really, I would very much like to do this with a single request instead of running to the DB twice in a row.

Now, some facts:
The records in the table can be grouped by the column `GROUP_ID_COLUMN`.
It is possible for multiple records that have the same `GROUP_ID_COLUMN` to match the same userInput. This means that the results in the `secondarySelect` are not distinct (several records are repeated).

Attempting to do this in 2 statements instead of three also creates problems.
My attempt looked like this:

```
var initialSelect = ctx.MY_TABLE
                    .Where(o => o.COLUMN1 == userInput1 && initSel.COLUMN2 == userInput2);

if(!string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput3))
{
    initialSelect = initialSelect.Where(o => o.COLUMN3.Contains(userInput3));
}

...
[More if()s of other columns]
...

initialSelect = initialSelect.Select(o => o.GROUP_ID_COLUMN);

var secondarySelect = from groups in ctx.MY_TABLE
                      join initialResults in initialSelect on groups.GROUP_ID_COLUMN equals initialResults.GROUP_ID_COLUMN
                      join finalResults in ctx.MY_TABLE on groups.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN equals finalResults.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN
                      select groups.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN;
```

Because, as I've mentioned, the initialSelect may return several records that have the same GROUP_ID_COLUMN, this means that for each repetition of GROUP_ID_COLUMN I get **all** of the records that belong to the group. This can be as little as 2 (or even 1) to as many as **a couple of hundreds**...
Adding [from...select...].Distinct() simply causes it to crash and throw some nonsensical Exception about the request to the DB being interrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

I solved it thusly. Note both `Distinct()` calls. I assume only the second one is **required** but I think having the first one as well should lower the number of iterations it needs to make later.

```
//ctx => my Entities context
//userInput1 => int, userInput2 => int
//DB table: PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN (INTEGER),  
            GROUP_ID_COLUMN (CHAR(16) FOR BIT DATA),  
            COLUMN1 (INTEGER),  
            COLUMN2 (INTEGER)
            COLUMN3 (VARCHAR(100))

var initialSelect = ctx.MY_TABLE
                    .Where(o => o.COLUMN1 == userInput1 && initSel.COLUMN2 == userInput2);

if(!string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput3))
{
    initialSelect = initialSelect.Where(o => o.COLUMN3.Contains(userInput3));
}

...
[More if()s of other columns]
...

initialSelect = initialSelect.Select(o => o.GROUP_ID_COLUMN).Distinct();


var secondarySelect = from finalResults in ctx.MY_TABLE
                      join (from groups in ctx.MY_TABLE
                            join initialResults in initialSelect on groups.GROUP_ID_COLUMN equals initialResults.GROUP_ID_COLUMN
                            select groups.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN).Distinct() on finalResults.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN equals groups.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN
                      select groups.PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN;
```